# quicker way of getting all the multiples of a number?

Tags: c, math, optimization

I'm trying to print all the multiples of a number N from N to K by using a for loop

```
    for(i=N;i<=K;i+=N)
        printf("%d\n", i);
```

I believe this is O(n) but I'm wondering if there is a quicker way of doing it. thanks

Comment: What is slow about this?

Comment: Since `printf` will be by far the most expensive operation in this loop, that doesn't really leave anything else to optimise.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" -- Donald Knuth

Comment: It's `O(N)` in the number of multiples, but `O(1/N)` really. Think about it, the higher the number, the less multiples before `k`.

Comment: Can you imagine to remove any instruction from that code snippet or to do something faster than a sum? Even if you cache the results in an array for future use...you won't do less work to read them!!!

Comment: Note that this code may exhibit **undefined behavior** if `K > INT_MAX - N`. **Overflow in signed arithmetic is undefined**. Use unsigned arithmetic with `unsigned i, K, N` and `"%u\n"` to avoid this.

Answer (score 3):

Since the size of your output is K/N, your solution must be at least O(K/N) (or as you called it, O(n)), because you wouldn't be able to create your entire output otherwise.

It is possible, however, to make non-algorithmic optimizations, such as minimizing the number of calls to printf (although I'm not sure if this will have any real effect over the performance).

Answer (score 0):

Since there's nothing to optimize in the loop arithmetic, what's left is the heavy weight `printf`. You could implement your own version of the (non-standard) `itoa()` here, converting the integer to a digit sequence.

But what exactly is too slow here? Are you I/O bound? CPU bound? Or just curious?